# Phpfox query with multiple joins

Tags: phpfox

This is my query:

```
 $aThreads = $this->database()->select('mf.parent_id,mf.forum_id,ff.user_id as favourite_id,ff.is_favourite,mf.name,ft.*,'.Phpfox::getUserField('u2','last_').'') 
                              ->from($this->_sTable, 'ft')
                              ->Join(Phpfox::getT('forum'), 'mf', 'mf.forum_id = ft.forum_id')
                              ->leftJoin(Phpfox::getT('user'),'u2', 'u2.user_id = ft.user_id')
                              ->leftJoin(Phpfox::getT('forum_favourite'), 'ff', 'u2.user_id = ff.user_id AND ft.thread_id = ff.thread_id')
                              ->where($mConditions)
                              ->execute('getSlaveRows');
```

I have to select two column values from `forum_favourite` table.

Columns in `forum_favourite` table `(thread_id,user_id,is_favourite)`. From this, I need to select `user_id and is_favourite`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Im not sure what exactly are you trying to do but if you just want to select more fields you can add them to the select part, for example:  ->select('table.field, mf.parent....

Comment: Please use proper stackoverflow syntax to asks questions.
Your question is badly formulated and it seems you haven't made some effort to research it.